# Book on linear algebraic groups in scheme language

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-groups

Is there a book on linear algebraic groups using the scheme language (i.e. not Springer or Borel, but like Waterhouse, but more in-depth)?

The book should discuss topics like Borel subgroups etc.

(Related question: [Books on reductive groups using scheme theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17662/books-on-reductive-groups-using-scheme-theory))

Comment: How about Jantzen's "Representations of Algebraic Groups"? http://home.imf.au.dk/jantzen/rags.ps

Comment: How about SGA3?

Comment: Demazure-Gabriel

Comment: I think it's hard to beat Demazaure–Gabriel, but it's more than a bit intimidating (the word 'magisterial' comes to mind).  Waterhouse has a distillation of some bits of it that looks nice and accessible (http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0547117), but it stops short of the structure theory for reductive groups.  Bruhat–Tits (http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0756316) have an extremely thorough (and occasionally accessible) treatment, but it's specialised to groups over valued fields.

Comment: Agreed, Demazure-Gabriel is hard to beat. Whatever you need after it, you can read any other book and translate from that language in your mind to scheme language. Milne's notes also have a promising future.

Comment: James Milne also has a book on his web site. If I remember correctly, he's still working on parts of it.

Comment: @stankewicz: Your link is to corrections for the first edition of Jantzen's book, which was republished in 2003 in a corrected and much expanded second edition by AMS.   (That too has minor faults, but so far my list of those is short.)   Anyway, *all* books mentioned here that include the Borel-Chevalley structure theory have to rely to some extent on other sources.   The subject is rich but doesn't allow for a completely self-contained account of finite length: too much algebraic geometry, group theory, category theory.  Milne's still incomplete book should be a useful synthesis.